# Weird character variable dont convert to numeric

Tags: input, sas, character, numeric

I have these txt New_Wireless_Fixed and when I read it using a data step, it reads the value for Sale/Funds but it does not convert it into numeric and when I try to clean it from other non-numeric character and then convert it, I only get missing values. I have been trying for two days and I can't make it work. Can someone told me what I am doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
Data df;
    Infile 'C:\Users\psuphare\ASP\New_Wireless_Fixed.txt';     
    Input 
        @1  AcctNo      $13.
        @15 ActDt       MMDDYY10.
        @26 DeactDt     MMDDYY10.
        @41 DeactReason $4.
        @46 GoodCredit  8.
        @55 RatePlan    8.
        @65 DealerType  $2.
        @68 Age         8.
        @80 Province    $2.
        @85 Sale        COMMA8.2        
        ;    

Run;
```

This is the dataset:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I2cmx9_HjIA7yzRUWg1axkmZjyrzL_yY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It is recommended to include all info with the post, instead of as a link to an external site (Google Drive). See [Is it OK to share files with Dropbox and other file-sharing services in posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266714/2745495).

Comment: Just ran your code on first 30 records and it works fine. What does go wrong exactly?

Comment: You need to show the NOTE:s from the LOG.  If you have a note that SAS went to a new line you may need the TRUNCOVER INFILE statement option.

Comment: Or perhaps you can use LRECL= and PAD option to emulate fix length records.

Answer (score 1):

I'll guess you need to use the INFILE statement option TERMSTR.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. Sorry about the file in the google drive, it was the only way I thought for sharing the dataset. The problem is not that SAS is not reading the text file into a table, the problem is that when I try to use that variable (Sale, label Funds) in an aggregate function, it does not work because it says the function needs a numeric input.